# Make Grid fit inside a path/object

Tags: inkscape

I want to make the grid fit inside the circle(remove the extra grid outside the circle). How can I achieve that in the simplest way? I have tried almost everything under the path menu but nothing helped.

(The grid was created using the extensions-> render -> grids)

[image]

Note: I would prefer a method that can be applied across any shape.

Comment: Hard to say your not defining the purpose. Id uselipping path. But wont fit all usecases.

Comment: @joojaa I am trying to make the center mesh of the Tennis racket.

Comment: yes but what do you need the end results to be. There is a level of reality that you are not aware here. You can think of lines as having no dimension in which case clipping path wont do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to hide it visually, duplicate your circle, make sure it's on top of the grid, select both, right-click and select 'Set Clip'.

Alternatively, you can make a clone of the circle instead of a duplicate, if you want it to automatically update when you change the shape of the circle.

If you actually need the underlying geometry gone (for laser-cutting for example), duplicate your circle, make sure it's on top, select both, use 'Path → Cut Path' and then 'Path → Break Apart'. Now you need to manually select and delete all lines outside the circle.